# Send data to Python with AJAX:method not allowed (405)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have a basic html page that contains a list on links. When the user click on the `button .extract` I am calling a javaScript method that convert those links to JSON data and send it to a python script via an AJAX call. I am collecting my data on Javascript but there is an error 405 with Python.

**index.html:**

```
<button onclick="getAllLinks()" id="exctract" class='pager pager-extract'>Extract</button>
```

**collector.js**

```
function postData(input){
    valid_input = JSON.stringify(input)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "store_query.py",
        data: { param: valid_input },
        async: false,
        success: callBackFunc
    });
}

function callBackFunc(response) {
    // do something with the response
    console.log(response);
}


function getAllLinks(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    postData(links)
}
```

**store_query.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect,url_for, request
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hi"
```

Comment: as default `flask` blocks all `POST` requests - you have to use `@app.route(..., methods=["POST", "GET"])`

Comment: string `"store_query.py"` is not URL - It is filename. You have `@app.route("/")` so you can connect only with `/` - in JavaScript `url: "/",`

Comment: how do you run this code ? You should run `app.run()` to start www server built-in in flask. And code should send HTML to browser. And server will wait for links from browser. You can't open `index.html` directly in web browser without running `app.run()`

Comment: @furas, I don't actully run anything as I thought I would be able to run a python script just by clicking on the index.html button.

Comment: you can't run `python` if you don't run web server which knows how to execute `python` code. Browser sends request to web server, server has to run Python code, and server sends result to browser. The same is with web servers which runs `PHP` - web server can't run `PHP` if it doesn't run code which know how to execute PHP code. (but usually web servers have preinstalled module to run PHP code)

Comment: thanks for details. I am running the html page locally with Visual Studio Live (port 5500). Actually, not sure if I needed all of this but what I am trying to achieve at the end is the write all the links present in the index.html on a .xlm / excel file. Right now, I have all the links in a js variable but since it seems pretty complicated to write on a file with js I told myself I should use ajax to send this variable to python and then rite on the .xml file with python

Comment: Visual Studion runs only `HTML` page but you have to run `app.run()` to run web server built-in in flask to get requests from browser. If you don't use `app.run()` then flask does't run and it can't get ajax requests.